# This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'SetStateAction<boolean>' are callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have a problem with setLiked

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Heart from "../heart/Heart";

const Cart: React.FC = (props) => {
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState<boolean>(false);
    return (
        <div className='cart'>
            <div className="cart-content">
                <div className="cart-items">
                    <h4>0 000 ₽</h4>
                    <Heart setLiked={setLiked} liked={liked} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Cart
```

I wrote on type HeartProps setLiked with React.SetStateAction and then got an error at click event setLiked(!liked)

```
import React from 'react';

import './heart.sass';

type HeartProps = {
    liked: boolean,
    setLiked: React.SetStateAction<boolean> 
}

const Heart: React.FC<HeartProps> = ({liked, setLiked}) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => setLiked(!liked)} className='heartButton'>
        </button>
    );
};

export default Heart;
```

if i would write on type HeartProps setLiked: React.SetStateAction // any
then it works correctly

Comment: Can you try to change the type to `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>`

Comment: Could someone explain this "answer"?